# Wait for array.map iterations in Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have the following code that should add items for customers if they dont already exist. Execution should be in parallel.

```
await Promise.all(
    customers.map(async (customer) => {
        return customer.items.map(async (item) => {
            return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
                const productExists = someArray.some(
                    (arrayValue) => arrayValue === item.id
                );
                if (!productExists) {
                    logger.info(
                    `customer item ${item.id} does not exist, creating...`
                    );
                    await createCustomerItem(item.id);
                    logger.info(`customer item ${item.id} created.`);

                    someArray.push(item.id);
                } else {
                    logger.info(`customer item ${item.id} already exists, skipping...`);
                }
                resolve(true);
            });
        });
    })

);

logger.info(`All items should now be present`);
```

The problem is that the execution is not waiting for `createCustomerItem` to resolve in the cases of `!productExists)`

This is the log

```
customer item 32310 does not exist, creating...
customer item ao does not exist, creating...
customer item ute does not exist, creating...
All items should not be present
customer item ao created.
customer item ute created.
customer item 32310 created.
```

Naturally `All items should not be present` should come last.

When all the items already exist, then the process looks good.

Comment: `map` knows nothing about promises,.  So unfortunately you can't use map this way.

Comment: I'd say it is because Promise.all expects an array of Promises, and you are passing it an array of arrays of Promises. Try flatMap instead.

Comment: I think what @JulienD has mentioned in their comment will resolve your issue.

Comment: ... or simply replace `return customer.items.map()`  with `return Promise.all(customer.items.map())`

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Answer (score 7):

you can do something like this

```
const fruitsToGet = ['apple', 'grape', 'pear']

const mapLoop = async () => {
  console.log('Start')

  const promises = await fruitsToGet.map(async fruit => {
    const numFruit = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(fruit), 1000)
    });
    return numFruit
  })
  const numFruits = await Promise.all(promises)
  console.log(numFruits)

  console.log('End')
}

mapLoop();
```

results

```
Start
["apple", "grape", "pear"]
End
```

[source](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/) [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/map-loop-await?file=index.ts)

Comment: This line: `const promises = await fruitsToGet.map(async fruit` does not need `await` nor `async`, it is redundant in this case.

Comment: @MichalMoravik true that! +1

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/flatMap):

```
await Promise.all(
    customers.flatMap(async (customer) => {
        return customer.items.map(async (item) => {
```

Instead of returning an array of array of Promises, it will flatten the content to a simple array of Promises, which is what `Promise.all` expects.

N.B. It is not apparent from your question if the grouping of items per customer needs to be conserved. If it does, note that this solution changes the data structure to a flattened list, so you lose the grouping. Either add some `customerId` in your `item`s, or try @blex's suggestion in comments.